# Android WebView - history.go(-1)

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a simple android app for a web developer.
I am having problems with history.go(-1) in WebView.

If I navigate from page 1, to page 2, and hit a button with history.go(-1), the webview navigates to page 1.

If I navigate from page 1, to page 2, to page 3, and hit button with history.go(-1), the webview goes to page 2. If I hit the button with history.go(-1) again, the webview goes to page 3, and not page 1.

Is this a fault in the webview of android? Works like a charm in iOS and on desktop browsers!
Is there a work around?

Comment: what are you using to deveelop this, are you using just java and xml or are you using jQuery or similar?

Answer (score 0):

for this you would need to use a Task and Back Stack, this will allow you to move to previous activities, avoiding the problem that you are running to. Have a look at 
[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html), you should see where you are going wrong and how to solve it